# Why are altimeters not affected by wind?

Tags: pressure

If you have a device that measures air pressure, surely high amounts of wind will affect the readings?

Is it not the case that airflow on and around an object affects the pressure?  (e.g. Bernoulli's principle)

How do skydiving altimeters give an accurate reading despite the wind?

Comment: IDK about skydiving altimeters, but in aircraft, the altimeter measures the pressure at a so-called [_static port_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitot-static_system). The location of the static port on the aircraft's fuselage is carefully chosen by the engineers such that the pressure there is minimally dependent on the aircraft's [_apparent wind_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_wind).

Comment: Possibly a better fit for [aviation.se].

Comment: I think, the question could be improved if you ask about effect, that affect that altimeter  accuracy... Because the answer probably really an engineering detail on how to avoid this systematic errors... But on the other hand, just understanding the systematic errors and their magnitude is legit question for physics.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent an altimeter (which is a very sensitive air pressure gauge) from being affected by the bernoulli effect (which would make the gauge read low) or the ram pressure effect (which would make the gauge read high), the sense port through which outside air enters the altimeter case is carefully protected from the wind with baffles and screens which filter out air *movement* and allow only static *pressure* to act on the gauge.